# Multiple log files using Log4j

Tags: log4j

I have a web application, that is build on spring webflow and jsf. Multiple users can log into my application at the same time. Now I want to use log4j to, of course, do the logging.

My question: is it possible to let log4j create different log files for every connected user?

thanks, Nikolaus

Comment: I don't know whether log4j can do it, but logback can (logback.qos.ch -- actually a rewrite of a logging system by the author of log4j himself)

Comment: sounds good. but is logback really working together with spring webflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, statically configured log4j cannot do it (unless your user set is constant and known upfront), you'd have to implement something on top of it that would set the configuration programatically.

If logback can do it, as *fge* says, use it, best not directly, but through slf4j.